# Is there a right or wrong for ownership in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to write "modern C++" Qt applications, meaning with as much RAII as possible. Therefore I ask myself if it is safe to use automatic allocation when possible like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QWidget window{};
    window.setWindowTitle("Der eine Knopf");
    QPushButton button{"Ende"};
    QObject::connect( &button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    QVBoxLayout layout{};
    layout.addWidget(&button);
    window.setLayout(&layout);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Whereas the original tutorial code had a lot of pointers and heap:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app{argc, argv};
  QWidget window{};
  window.setWindowTitle("Hallo Qt");
  QPushButton button = new QPushButton("Ende");
  QObject::connect( button, SIGNAL(clicked()),
      &app, SLOT(quit()));
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(button);
  window.setLayout(layout);
  window.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

I am aware of Qt's ownership concept of `QObject`s in general. So I assume the second example is correct. I assume that `setLayout` and `addWidget` also change the ownership and thus no explicit `delete` is needed for me as a client.

And assuming that I wonder -- why does my first example work then? If those methods acquire ownership, will they not `delete` their newly acquired children in the end? If they do, will my program not crash because the objects are removed twice? (The program does not crash, I would have mentioned that. But that could be by accident, right?)

I am now so much confused who owns whom and how does it work that I do not know how it could. The one rule I heard was "Qt will take care of that" -- but "of what"? And of what not?

Well, obviously I am new to Qt and what I would like is some insights into the `QObject`s constructor and destructor counts. Or messages for each construction and/or destruction. Is there such a facility in Qt?

Comment: I believe the fact your app is not crashing is by accident. That is because `QObjects` remove themselves from their parent's object trees in their destructor. If you were to change the order of construction of your widgets on the stack then when the parent is destroyed before the child, it will attempt to delete the child, but the child was created on the stack, so you'll SEGV

Comment: See [object trees and ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Comment: @SteveLorimer "remove themselves from their parents tree"... yeah... that could work. You believe... hrm. I will read up on this via the link from thuga.

Comment: @thuga that is _exactly_ what I was looking for, in all points. If you make that an answer that would be one I would "accept".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [object trees and ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html), when you use automatic allocation you have to watch out for the order of creation. *The destructors of local objects are called in reverse order of their constructors*.

So in your example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QWidget window{};
    window.setWindowTitle("Der eine Knopf");
    QPushButton button{"Ende"};
    QObject::connect( &button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    QVBoxLayout layout{};
    layout.addWidget(&button);
    window.setLayout(&layout);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Here you create a `QWidget` object called `window`. Then you create a `QPushButton`. You set a layout to your widget, and add the `button` to that layout. The layout will automatically set `window` as the parent of `button`. But when you exit your application and the scope ends, `button` will be destroyed first. And upon its destruction it will be removed from `window`'s list of children. So it won't be destroyed twice.

However if you create `button` before `window`, `window` will be destroyed before `button`, and it will also destroy all of it's children. Which means it will also call the destructor of `button`. After this the destructor of `button` will be called again as it went out of scope. So here you would have a big problem.